# MySQL override auto_increment?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a messaging system (using PHP) and want to assign an ID number to each message (aside from each actual message having an unique ID number)...however, if someone replies to a message then i want to be able to give that message the same ID as the message being replied to...then of course I can disply them by time and show them in order.

So, if i give the field an auto_increment type is that able to be overwritten?

Meaning...each new message has auto value e.g. 1, 2, 3 etc but someone replies to number 2 so it's ID needs to also 2

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Add another field, e.g. `conversation_id` or something like that. auto_increment is for _unique_ identifiers.

Comment: Why not add an extra field called "reply_id" and add id of the message you're replying to?

Comment: @VolkerK Yeah but how do i assign it an id?

Comment: @Darren Sweeney, you could use the id of the first message in a conversation as the conversation_id.

Comment: @VolkerK agreed but is it possible to get it without updating table with last_insert_id or something like? I basically want to fill two fields with same number but only if msg is not a reply

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely nothing prevents you from assigning any arbitrary value to an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. If necessary, the table counter will adjust accordingly.

However, you cannot set as `AUTO_INCREMENT` a column that's not unique.

Honestly, I can't understand your design. A typical messaging system would look like this:

```
message_id in_reply_to
========== ===========
         1        NULL
         2        NULL
         3           1
         4        NULL
         5           1
         6           3
         7        NULL
```

Duplicating IDs kind of beats the purpose of using IDs.

**Update #1:** OMG, it seems that it can actually be done under certain circumstances:

> For MyISAM tables you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column
>   in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1
>   WHERE prefix=given-prefix. This is useful when you want to put data
>   into ordered groups.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html

**Update #2:** For the records, I've just tested it and you can use duplicate auto-incremented IDs in InnoDB tables as well:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    foo_id INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    bar_id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (foo_id),
    INDEX bar_id (bar_id)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - If you are interested in the subject, I suggest you read the manual page I link. There're many subtleties about `AUTO_INCREMENT` that many people is not aware of, including me.

Comment: This is really interesting. Definitely going to read up on this for my own knowledge. Thanks for the research / testing, @ÁlvaroG.Vicario

Answer (score 1):

No, auto_increment columns cannot occur multiple times.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say

Answer (score 1):

I would keep each message ID unique - whether it is via auto increment or a uuid. Add an additional column to the message structure for thread_id - unique on creation, and then have all replies include this thread_id to link them together logically.

Answer (score 1):

The way you would do this is have another column in your table called `parent_id` or something of the sort.

The original message would have a parent_id of NULL.

Then, when anyone posts a reply to a message, then the original ID of the message goes into the `parent_id` column of the new message. For instance:

```
id    text           parent_id    created_at
============================================
1    'Lorem ipsum'     null         [time]
2    'Lorem ipsum'     1            [time]
3    'Lorem ipsum'     1            [time]
```

You could even go further and have the replies nested:

```
id    text           parent_id    created_at
============================================
1    'Lorem ipsum'     null         [time]
2    'Lorem ipsum'     1            [time]
3    'Lorem ipsum'     2            [time]
```

In the latter case, you'd probably need some sort of recursive function to get all of the nested messages; the first way is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to put unique id is; to add uniqid(rand()).